# I find I can/am/do something

Tags: meaning, phrases

This is a quote by D.H.Lawrence:

> I only know that my body doesn’t by any means gravitate to all I meet
>   or know, **I find I can** shake hands with a few people. But most I
>   wouldn’t touch with a long prop.

I have seen this structure, I find I do something, or I find I am something, so many times. For example **I find I'm so excited**. Now I want to know here what is the meaning of "to find". Does it imply I **know** I can/am/do...?

Comment: When Lawrence met certain people, he discovered that he felt comfortable shaking hands with them. This wasn't the case with most people he met.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common phrase to describe what happens when a person learns something about themselves, often with a suggestion of mild surprise. See [Merriam-Webster on "find"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find).

> 3a: to discover by the intellect or the feelings : [experience](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experience)
>
> *find much pleasure in your company*

Comment: I experience I am so excited. I experience I can shake hands with a few people. Do you think these are reasonable sentences?!

Comment: That's non-idiomatic. The phrase is "I find," not "I experience." But there's always a suggestion of mild surprise, so the sentence, "I find I am so excited," suggests that previously you were not able to feel excitement. It suggests a change.